# Is it possible to view tensor-board (distributions/histograms) "live" as model is training

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorboard

I am using Google-colab to build and train a model. I am using tensorboard within Google-colab to visualize the model. What I do is start tensorboard and then train the model, although tensorboard will not update to let me visualize the histograms and distributions until after training has ended. Is there a way to actually view the histograms and distributions live as the model is being trained?